# Resize Eclipse RCP Part

Tags: eclipse, resize, rcp, e4

I'm creating an application using eclipse RCP, I have many Part and I want to resize them. Some of these parts don't need many space.

I've checked in Application.4xmi but I didn't found anything helpful.

Any ideas?

Comment: post the code you tried with.

Comment: There is no code yet ! I did'nt knew that I need to write a code to resize a Part ?! Do I need to implement/create a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the size of a `Trimmed Window` in the Application.e4xmi by setting the `Bounds` width and height values.

Usually you then use `PartSashContainer` to divide up the window. You specify a percentage used for each child in the `Container Data` for the child.

Comment: Thanks ! I've setted value in `Container data` text area

Comment: Note that what you put in the `Container Data` shouldn't be a _percentage_ - rather, a relative value, and, as [pointed out here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#e4uiconcept_container), if you make it too coarse (e.g. "30" for one part and "70" for the other), it will result in jerky resizing behaviour. Using larger values (e.g. "3000" and "7000", i.e. more than available pixels) for a 30:70 ratio will make it smoother.