# How to Programatically resize Detached Viewpart Window in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, window-resize, swt-awt

I have a Viewpart in Eclipse RCP which I am detaching using inbuild method.
Now I have a button on that Detached ViewPart and Upon Clicking it window Size of Windows (in Which detached Viewpart is there) should increase but I can't find any API for the Same.
Can Anyone Please Help ?

There is this one Question I found but still don't know how to do this
[Resize Eclipse RCP Part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260924/resize-eclipse-rcp-part)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the size of the `Shell` containing the part.

For example, this command handler increases the size of the shell containing the active part by 100 pixels in each direction:

```java
public class ResizeHandler extends AbstractHandler
{
  @Override
  public Object execute(final ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException
  {
    // Get the active part

    IWorkbenchPart part = HandlerUtil.getActivePart(event);

    // Get the shell from the part site

    Shell shell = part.getSite().getShell();

    Point size = shell.getSize();

    // Set new size

    shell.setSize(size.x + 100, size.y + 100);

    return null;
  }  
}
```

Note: The question you linked to is talking about the new 'e4' API. Since you are asking about `ViewPart` you are using the 3.x compatibility API.

Comment: Worked Like charm ...
Thank you :)